# Including resources in subdirectories of src/main/resources with Maven build

Tags: java, maven, inputstream

I have a Maven project that I use Eclipse to write.
I have a hierarchical src/main/resources such that file1.zip is located in a main directory, which file2.zip and file3.zip are located in a sub-directory of file1.zip.

```
src/main/resources
    models/modelA/file1.zip
    models/modelA/subdirectory1
          file2.zip
    models/modelA/subdirectory2
          file3.zip
```

my pom.xml file has this included

```
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/models</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.zip</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I load the resource as

```
String file1 = "/models/modelA/file1.zip";
String file2 = "/models/modelA/subdirectory1/file2.zip";
String file2 = "/models/modelA/subdirectory1/file3.zip";
InputStream is1 = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file1);
InputStream is2 = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file2);
InputStream is3 = getClass().getResourceAsStream(file3);
```

When running the program after mvn package, everything is works.
But when I try to run this in Eclipse, is2 and is3 are always null.

The src/main/resources are in my class path. 
How can I get this to run also in Eclipse?

I should mention I have looked at the SO posts
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547488/filenotfoundexception-in-src-main-resources)
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar)
and many others that do not give an answer to the difference between it working with Eclipse and Maven

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22117293/4121573

Comment: The only issue I see is that resource directory is `src/main/resources/models` instead of `src/main/resources/` which would make `/models` part unnecessary when loading the resource. But then `is1` would also be null, hm.. Maybe it's not null because of previous experiments? BTW, you can check if Maven worked as expected by looking into `target/classes` dir - there you'd see your zip files and folders.

Comment: @Adonis I did what that post said, and still get is2 and is3 as null

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev target/classes has all files and the package runs accordingly

Comment: Well if what you see in `target/classes` is correct - then the problem is not in Maven.  That's where Maven did its part. The other part is loading resource - maybe paths are incorrect or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Eclipse not allow me to create sub folders correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116913/why-does-eclipse-not-allow-me-to-create-sub-folders-correctly)

Comment: @Rich your contribution was exactly first comment, in which I replied that I had already performed that operation and still not working.

Comment: Is it a bad practice to use multiple subfolders in the resources folder? For instance mimic the main structure of folders? I often also have path issues and I am wondering whether my problem is to create multiple subfolders

Comment: I was just looking for this issue too and found this post that might help 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504204/maven-copy-multiple-files-from-different-resource-folders-to-a-single-tagert-fol